# How to get interface GETWAY with two WANs

Tags: networking, bash, dhclient

I have 2 ISP connetions, first ISP use mac binding, second use PPPoE

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
auto lan
allow-hotplug gembird-white
allow-hotplug gembird-black

iface lo inet loopback

iface lan inet static
  address 192.168.1.1/24

iface gembird-white inet dhcp
  hwaddress ether 64:70:02:XX:XX:XX

iface gembird-black inet dhcp

auto dsl-provider
iface dsl-provider inet ppp
pre-up /bin/ip link set gembird-black up
provider dsl-provider
```

Afet boot I am manualy runs my balance.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

IF1="gembird-white"   # WAN interface 1
IF2="ppp0"            # WAN interface 2

GW1="188.230.111.1"
GW2="62.122.200.239"
W1=1
W2=2

route del default
ip route add default scope global nexthop via $GW1 dev $IF1 weight $W1 nexthop dev $IF2 weight $W2
```

The problem is that first provider give me dynamic IP and dynamic GW, that can change.

I don't know how to get gateway from my first ISP, because after boot ppp is already up and

**route -n**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp0
188.230.111.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 gembird-white
...
```

Help me please with it

And where is right place to run my **balance.sh**???